# Completely private browser installation using TrueCrypt

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, encryption, truecrypt

I have a TrueCrypt partition on my Windows 7 Pro 64-bit computer. I have Firefox and Chrome installed on my OS as normal, but I would like to have a completely private browser installed on my TrueCrypt partition--another copy of one of the two (preferably Chrome, but either is fine) installed completely independently on the partition. I don't want anyone to know that the separate installation even exists unless they can somehow get access to the encrypted partition.

Is this even possible? If not, what would be the best alternative?

Comment: Live disk version of linux? A VM running in a steady state? Persistent data?

Comment: Portable copy of Firefox?

Comment: If you're that paranoid, I would just encrypt the whole drive and make it a policy to always lock/suspend your computer everytime you leave it. Remember, it's easy to find/write your own undetectable keylogger so if anyone has access to your unencrypted OS they could plant it easily. Also, check @Cong Xu answer since you probably want to protect your traffic from snooping too.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a portable version of chrome: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable. It is usually meant to be used on a portable drive (e.g. usb drive), but I think this would suit your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and copy it into your truecrypt partition. There is no installation, and using tor means your traffic is encrypted, so people can't easily figure out what you're visiting via snooping network traffic.

Then again I have to ask why you need to do this; perhaps using the private browsing modes in the installed browsers is good enough.

Comment: True. Private modes won't save any track anyway. Except perhaps he did want to keep the tracks (bookmark and preference etc), and thus the Tor Bundle (or any other portable browser) is the answer because of its portability. +1 because using Tor would protect his traffic too.